# why does object moving towards axis of rotation on disk create toque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum

> According to my prof, if there is an object let's say an ant on a rotating disk at the edge of the disk and the ant starts to go up to the axis of rotation, there is a torque. Why is this?

What I do know is that the I values and the W values changes but I wasn't sure how this has to do anything with the torque changing?

Answer (score 4):

I am sure you are familiar with Newton's second law of motion, which defines force as a rate of change of momentum.

$$ F =\frac{d P}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dt}+v\frac{dm}{dt}$$

In rotational motion, torque $(\tau)$, moment of intertia $(I)$ and angular velocity $(\omega)$ are equivalent to force $(F)$, mass $(m)$ and velocity $(v)$ respectively.

Just like force is defined as rate of change of momentum $(P)$, torque is defined as rate of change of angular momentum $(L)$.

$$\tau= \frac{dL}{dt}$$

$$\tau=I\frac{d\omega}{dt} + \omega\frac{dI}{dt}$$

The rate of change of inertia is the source of torque when object moves towards the axis of rotation.